# Backing Conversion Software

Tags: documents4j

the documents4j.com page states under Local

> "The local API implementation delegates a document conversion to an application on the same machine which is capable of applying the requested conversion. For this to work, the executing machine **requires an installation of the backing conversion software such as for example MS Word or MS Excel**. documents4j offers a simple mechanism for registering custom converters **but ships with implementations of such converters for MS Word and MS Excel for Windows**."

I'm confused. The 1st bolded phrase seems to contradict the second bolded phrase.
1. Please, Can you clarify?
2. What is the backing conversion software?

Thank you

Comment: documents4j already come with converters for MS Word and MS Excel, but you still need these applications installed for the converters.

Answer (score 1):

Converters only contain Java implementations that hook into official document processing APIs. It provides out of the box support for Word and Excel, but those programs must be seperatly installed and licensed.